# How to read the filepath into the variable?

Tags: ftp

My requirement is to transfer the files using FTP command. I have used csv to store the details of source and destination file paths.

```
while IFS="," read SRC_IP SRC_UNAME SRC_PSWD SRC_PATH SRC_FILE DEST_PATH
do
ftp -n $SRC_IP <<END_SCRIPT   
 quote USER $SRC_UNAME  
     quote PASS $SRC_PSWD
        binary        
        cd "$SRC_PATH"
        lcd "$DEST_PATH"
        prompt
        get $SRC_FILE
        quit
END_SCRIPT
done < Input.csv
```

All the file names and path are correct but still I get below error:

```
A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

I am thinking the issue is with reading the file path into the variable.(e.g. `$SRC_PATH`).
Can anyone please tell me how to read the filepath into the variable.

Comment: To debug this, you can change the cd and lcd commands to "echo" and see if you get what you entered. If you do, then it's another problem.

Comment: You should probably add the `-r` switch to your `read` command, especially if your file contains Windows-style pathnames (i.e. backslash separators)

Answer (score 0):

Below Code worked. I have moved cd command before FTP command.

clear
while IFS="," read SRC_IP SRC_UNAME SRC_PSWD SRC_PATH SRC_FILE DEST_PATH
do
cd $DEST_PATH
ftp -n $SRC_IP <